# Audio using PyGame Subset for Android

Tags: android, python, audio, pygame, subset

I am trying to play a simple wav file using PyGame Subset for Android. I can't seem to get it working. Does anyone have any example code working? There isn't any examples in the documentation.

Comment: Can you provide us with some example code? If you have a code that fails, you could post it here to see where you are at.

Comment: When I run [this](http://pastebin.com/zCm75DHM) the program crashes on my phone. `yum = android.mixer.Sound("yum.wav"); yum.play` should play the sound once.

Comment: Can you debug the application somehow? Can you access error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Pygame Subset for Android documentation, you should be able to play sounds using `android_mixer`. Start by importing it [[1]](http://pygame.renpy.org/api.html#android_mixer):

```
import android_mixer as mixer
```

Now use the mixer just as a common pygame mixer to play sounds:

```
mixer.music.load(sys.argv[1])
mixer.music.play()
```

Please note that "the init and pre_init methods work, but are ignored - Android chooses appropriate settign automatically" as well as that "Only filenames and true file objects can be used - file-like objects will probably not work". Some other restrictions apply as well.  [[1]](http://pygame.renpy.org/api.html#android_mixer).

Comment: `import android_mixer as mixer` worked. I thought the mixer was located in the "android" module, I didn't realize it was in its own separate module. Thanks.